# Basic ElasticSearch + WordNet synonyms set-up with pre-existing index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to learn how to properly add "synonym functionality" to my existing ElasticSearch set up. Here's what I understand so far about the process. I'd appreciate it if you could point out any misunderstandings I have - I'm very new to elasticsearch.

From [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) I've learned that I need to add a synonym analyser and a synonym filter with a path to my synonyms file to my index config so that it looks like this:

```
{
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["synonym"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "format" : "wordnet",
                    "synonyms_path" : "analysis/wordnet_synonyms.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) I've learned how to add an analyser:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/_close'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex/_settings' -d '{
  "analysis" : {
    "analyzer":{
      "synonym":{
        "tokenizer":"whitespace",
        "filter" : ["synonym"]
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/_open'
```

But I don't know how to add the filter. Would it be as simple as this?:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/_close'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex/_settings' -d '{
  "analysis" : {
    "filter":{
      "synonym":{
         "type" : "synonym",
         "format" : "wordnet",
         "synonyms_path" : "analysis/wordnet_synonyms.txt",
         "ignore_case" : true
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/_open'
```

I also don't know where the `analysis/wordnet_synonyms.txt` is relative to. On [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) it says "relative to the `config` location". Where is the `config` location? In `etc/elasticsearch` somewhere (on Ubuntu)? Thanks!

**Edit:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33147705/993683) gives this as a solution:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/_close'
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex/_settings' -d '{
"analysis" : {
    "analyzer" : {
        "synonym" : {
            "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
            "filter" : ["synonym"]
        }
    },
    "filter":{
      "synonym":{
         "type" : "synonym",
         "format" : "wordnet",
         "synonyms_path" : "analysis/wordnet_synonyms.txt",
         "ignore_case" : true
      }
}'
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myindex/_open'
```

Is this possible? A commenter said that the index would need to be recreated when changing analyser settings - is this true? And I'm still not sure where to put "wordnet_synonyms.txt".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to first delete your index and then create it with the analyzer and synonym token filter, like this (I've also added a mapping type and a dummy field to show you how to use your analyzer):

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/myindex

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/myindex -d '{
  "settings": {
     "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["synonym"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "format" : "wordnet",
                    "synonyms_path" : "analysis/wordnet_synonyms.txt"
                }
            }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings": {
     "typename": {
        "fieldname": {
           "type": "string",
           "analyzer": "synonym"
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

You need to put the `analysis/wordnet_synonyms.txt` file in the same folder as your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file. On Ubuntu, it would be in

```
/etc/elasticsearch/analysis/wordnet_synonyms.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I was looking for a way to do it to a pre-existing index, but if there isn't a way I'll accept your answer as is.

Comment: The only issue is that your field already exists. You can definitely modify settings and add a new field with your new analyzer, but you cannot add the analyzer to an already existing field.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!